# convert list of list into string with python

Tags: python

i have the below list of list that i 'd like to convert into a string:

```
[['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
 ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'O'], 
 ['O', ' ', '.', ' ', 'O', 'O', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'O'], 
 ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'O'], 
 ['O', ' ', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', ' ', 'O', '.', 'O'], 
 ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'U'], 
 ['O', ' ', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', 'O'], 
 ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'O'], 
 ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], 
 ['O', ' ', '.', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'O'], 
 ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', ' ']]
```

i'd like as a result:

```
OOOOOOOOOO
O O    O O
O . OO   O
O O O   XO
O OOOO O.O
O O O    U
O OOOOOO.O
O O      O
O O OOOOOO
O . O    O
OOOOOOOOOO
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: OK. What did you try? Can you show your attempt please? Explain what difficulties you are having. StackOverflow is *not* a code writing service. You have to illustrate what difficulties you are having in your own attempt at this problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a free code writing service.

Comment: ok ok don't get nervous here i'm just new to this site and to Python.

Comment: You need to show that you tried at least something and faced a problem. Here you're not even asking a question, you're asking us to do something for you. If you come accross a problem, there will be many people here who will be happy to help you, but nobody's here to work for free or do homework. Please read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = [['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'O'], ['O', ' ', '.', ' ', 'O', 'O', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'O'], ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'X', 'O'], ['O', ' ', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', ' ', 'O', '.', 'O'], ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'U'], ['O', ' ', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', '.', 'O'], ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'O'], ['O', ' ', 'O', ' ', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O'], ['O', ' ', '.', ' ', 'O', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', 'O'], ['O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', 'O', ' ']]

print('\n'.join([''.join(t) for t in lst])+'\n')
```

The above code will result in :

```
'OOOOOOOOOO\nO O    O O\nO . OO  XO\nO O O   XO\nO OOOO O.O\nO O O    U\nO OOOOOO.O\nO O      O\nO O OOOOOO\nO . O    O\nOOOOOOOOOO \n'
```

Comment: `'\n'.join(map(''.join, L))` Actually.

Comment: @DanD. Good answer ! You should post it :-)

Answer (score 0):

i did try a loop

for i in L:
    laby="".join(i)
but this resulted as converting only the first list of the list.

the '\n'.join(map(''.join, L)) solution works perfectly thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use comments, you know.